# Accessing non-const members in list of objects

Tags: c++, list, stl, constants

I would like to access members of objects contained in a list of such objects.

I have a class `CApp` with a member `std::list<Particle> PList` serving as a list of particles.

A class `Particle` has a member `void Update()` which from my understanding of const can't be const because it affects the instance (euler integration and stuff).

I would like to iterate through PList to update all of the particles.

A Particle constructor includes:

```
Particle::Particle(std::list<Particle>* PList_In) {
    PList = PList_In;
    PList->push_back(*this);
}
```

The following is called several times:

```
Particle(&PList);
```

So the list appears to be set up. As a side note, if anyone could explain what's actually there in terms of memory (pointers, references) at this point that would be great.

But basically this errs:

```
// Update all particles
std::list<Particle>::const_iterator iter;
for (iter = PList.begin(); iter != PList.end(); iter++) {
    iter->Update();
}
```

with

```
error: passing ‘const Particle’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘void Particle::Update()’ discards qualifiers
```

Not sure what to do with this, if more information/explanation is required, let me know.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using const_iterator you say that you don't want to change list elements.

If you want to, use std::list::iterator.

Answer (score 1):

By using `const_iterator` you are telling the compiler that you are not going to use this iterator on methods which *modify* the pointed to objects. Whether a method modifies the object or not is determined by its const qualifier. For example if you have a method declaration like `int get() const;` inside `class A` then this method is guaranteeing that it will not modify objects of `class A`. In your case it seems `Update` is not having the const qualifier hence the compiler is complaining that you can not call a non-const function using a `const_iterator`. You need to change the iterator type `std::list<Particle>::iterator`.

As a side note consider passing the `list` object by reference instead of using the pointer in your function.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the reference versus pointer please? How and a little why?

Comment: @Miles: See this FAQ: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/references.html#faq-8.6